# Cannot access service from controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an angular project, where I'm adding new functionality to an older project.
I'm trying to register a service with my controller but getting an error where my controller is unable to find the functions in the service.

Here's how my controller is defined (I know it's not the standard way, but I have to follow this because the entire application does.)

```
angular.module("test").controller("listCtrl", listCtrl);
listCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$state", "$timeout", "listService", "$rootScope"];

function listCtrl($scope, $state, $timeout, listService, $rootScope ) {
  this.$scope= $scope;

  $scope.service=listService;
  //some other definitions

  $scope.items = $scope.service.getPage(%function_ARGUMENTS%);

}
```

Here's how the service is defined:

```
angular.module("test").service("listService", listService);
listService.$inject = ['$state', '$rootScope'];

function listService($state, $rootScope) {
   function getPage(%function_ARGUMENTS%) {
     //getPage function definition goes here
   }
}
```

Now, for some reason, I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'getPage' of undefined

I cannot figure out what might be causing this.
Is the problem with how `$scope` is defined? If yes, then what would be the correct way to do this, assuming `this.$scope=$scope` cannot be modified.

**EDIT:** Fixed the plural typo in the question. I do not have that typo in my program, it was a mistake I made while typing on SO.

Comment: You have typo in `$scope.services.getPage(%function_ARGUMENTS%);` it must be `$scope.service.getPage(%function_ARGUMENTS%);`

Comment: I fixed the typo in the question, the typo isn't what's causing the error in my main program.

Comment: I posted answer too, anyways, you figured out the problem is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is expected as you have defined `$scope.service` where as using `$scope.services` notice additional "s".  So use correct variable

```
$scope.items = $scope.service.getPage(%function_ARGUMENTS%);
```

However, you will s till get another error as the function `getPage` with associated  with return service object.

```
function listService($state, $rootScope) {
   this.getPage = function() {
     //getPage function definition goes here
   }
}
```

OR,

```
function listService($state, $rootScope) {
   function getPage () {
     //getPage function definition goes here
   }

   this.getPage = getPage;
}
```

Comment: Fixed the typo in the question. Your answer helped. I didn't register the function to the service. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module("test").factory("listService", listService);
listService.$inject = ['$state', '$rootScope'];    

function listService($state, $rootScope) {
   return {
      function getPage(%function_ARGUMENTS%) {
         //getPage function definition goes here
      }
   }
}
```

Just write above as you Service function.

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed:
$scope.items = $scope.services.getPage(%function_ARGUMENTS%);

should be:
$scope.items = $scope.service.getPage(%function_ARGUMENTS%);

$scope.service was pluralized on that line when it should be singular.

As well you are using a service service, which is a constructor function. Therefore you need to reference your properties with the this keyword. The angular service method creates the object internally using the new keyword. You could try a factory:

```
angular.module("test")
  .factory("listService", listService);
  listService.$inject = ['$state', '$rootScope'];

  function listService($state, $rootScope) {
    function getPage(%function_ARGUMENTS%) {
      //getPage function definition goes here
    }
    return {
      getPage: getPage
    };
 }
```

This is more similar to what you had and you do not need to use the `this` keyword since it not a constructor function.

Hope this helps!

Cheers